# Why does GNU script use two forks instead of select and one fork?

Tags: c, linux, unix, gnu

I just realised that the "script" binary on GNU linux is using two forks instead of one.
It could simply use select instead of doing a first fork(). Why would it use two forks ?

Is it simply because select did not exist at the time it has been coded and nobody had the motivation to recode it or is there a valid reason ?

man 1 script: http://linux.die.net/man/1/script

script source: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=br8QXRUT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is in the code, which I have added some comments to.

```
child = fork();
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &unblock_mask, NULL);

if (child < 0) {
    warn(_("fork failed"));
    fail();
}
if (child == 0) {
            /* child of first fork */
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &block_mask, NULL);
    subchild = child = fork();
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &unblock_mask, NULL);

    if (child < 0) {
        warn(_("fork failed"));
        fail();
    }
    if (child) {
                    /* child of second fork runs 'dooutput' */
        if (!timingfd)
            timingfd = fdopen(STDERR_FILENO, "w");
        dooutput(timingfd);
    } else
                    /* parent of second fork runs 'doshell' */
        doshell();
} else {
    sa.sa_handler = resize;
    sigaction(SIGWINCH, &sa, NULL);
}
    /* parent of first fork runs doinput */
doinput();
```

There are thus three process running:

1. `dooutput()`
2. `doshell()`
3. `doinput()`

I think you are asking why use three processes, not one process and `select()`. `select()` has existed since ancient UNIX history, so the answer is unlikely to be that `select()` did not exist. The answer is more prosaic. `doshell()` needs to be in a separate process anyway, as what it does is `exec` the shell with appropriately piped fds. You thus need at least one fork. Writing `dooutput()` and `doinput()` within a `select()` loop looks to me perfectly possible, but it is actually easier to use blocking I/O rather than have to worry about using `select` etc. As `fork()` is relatively lightweight (given UNIX's CoW semantics) and there is little need for communication between the two processes, why use `select()` when `fork()` is perfectly good and produces smaller code? IE the real answer is 'why not?'

Comment: I perfectly understand all of that. I know the use of select will be a bit more complicated than a simple fork but is there a difference at a performance level ? Would it be a plus to use select ?

Comment: It depends on the circumstances (Stephen's has a fair amount to say). If the two processes are independent in operation (as they are here) so there is no IPC overhead, I would have thought there would be little difference in performance. The only way to know would be to recode it yourself and try it. However, it is unlikely performance is more important to `screen` than provable reliability. I'd code it the way they did.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that select is older than script. select came in with BSD sockets, and there was quite a bit of ancient unix history before that. From a quick look through minnie.tuhs.org it seems they showed up at about the same time, so if select did exist, maybe it was still being thought of as "something you use on sockets"

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Interesting. So I did some research. Stephens says (p396) `select` was introduced with 4.2BSD (Aug 1983) and SVR4 (Oct 1988). Did `screen` exist before 1988 or 1983? And did *GNU* `screen` exist before then? Unsurprisingly, the repo doesn't go back that far.